# C++ template when the template's function is not the same

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

Now I have a template class

```
template <class T>
class b
{
    void someFunc() {
        T t;
        t.setB();
    }
};
```

I know the template T only will be instantiated into 2 classes.

```
class D
{
public:
     void setB();
};

class R
{
public:
     void SetB();
};
```

As we can see, class D's function name **setB** is not the same as R's function **SetB**. So in template class b I cannot only just use setB. So is there some method if I cannot revise D or R? Can I add some wrapper or trick into the template class to solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot call a function on a type like that, did you mean T::setB() ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for confusion.

Comment: I have an idea on how you invoke the template, but it is not given in your example. Can you please add the usage of the template for us. And your code is illegal, so it is bad for an example!

Comment: Almost none of your code is legal C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a trait class can help you:

```
struct Lower {};
struct Upper {};

// trait for most cases
template <typename T>
struct the_trait {
    typedef Lower Type;
};
// trait for special cases
template <>
struct the_trait<R> {
    typedef Upper Type;
};

template <class T>
class b {
public:
    void foo() {
        foo_dispatch(typename the_trait<T>::Type());
    }
private:
    void foo_dispatch(Lower) {
        T t;
        t.setB();
    }
    void foo_dispatch(Upper) {
        T t;
        t.SetB();
    }
};
```

As @Arunmu pointed, this technique is also known as [Tag Dispatching](http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/cpp/techniques.php#tag_dispatching).

Comment: Maybe you should mention the technique name 'tag dispatching' (?) Upto you.

Answer (score 2):

You can specialise your template for the class that has different semantics:

```
template<>
class b<R>
{
    void doWork() {
        R obj;
        obj.SetB();
        // or R::SetB() if it was a static method.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using self programmed traits you can also check for the existence of a function with SFINAE.

If you want to switch your called method only one of them must exist in each class. My method provided will not work if the check find more then one of the tested methods!

The following example is written for C++14 but can also be used with c++03 if you replace the new library functions with self implemented ones ( which is of course not convenient )

The testing class has_Foo and has_Bar can also be embedded in a preprocessor macro, but I wrote it expanded to makes the things easier to read.

How it works and why there are some more intermediate steps are necessary are explained in the comments. See below!

```
    #include <iostream>


    // First we write two classes as example. Both classes represents
    // external code which you could NOT modify, so you need an
    // adapter to use it from your code.
    class A
    {
        public:
            void Foo() { std::cout << "A::Foo" << std::endl; }
    };

    class B
    {
        public:
            void Bar() { std::cout << "B::Bar" << std::endl; }
    };

    // To benefit from SFINAE we need two helper classes which provide
    // a simple test functionality. The solution is quite easy...
    // we try to get the return value of the function we search for and
    // create a pointer from it and set it to default value nullptr.
    // if this works the overloaded method `test` returns the data type
    // one. If the first test function will not fit, we cat with ... all
    // other parameters which results in getting data type two.
    // After that we can setup an enum which evaluates `value` to
    // boolean true or false regarding to the comparison function.


    template <typename T>
    class has_Foo
    {
        using one = char;
        using two = struct { char a; char b;};
        template <typename C> static one test( typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<C>().Foo())>::type*  );  
        template <typename C> static two test( ... ) ; 

        public:
        enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
        enum { Yes = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(one) };
        enum { No = !Yes };
    };

    template <typename T>
    class has_Bar
    {
        using one = char;
        using two = struct { char a; char b;};
        template <typename C> static one test( typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<C>().Bar())>::type*  );  
        template <typename C> static two test( ... ) ; 

        public:
        enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
        enum { Yes = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(one) };
        enum { No = !Yes };
    };


    // Now in your adapter class you can use the test functions
    // to find out which function exists. If your class
    // contains a Foo function the first one compiles and if the
    // the class contains a Bar function the second one fits. SFINAE
    // disable the rest.
    // We need a call helper here because SFINAE only 
    // fails "soft" if the template parameter can deduced from the
    // given parameters to the call itself. So the method
    // Call forwards the type to test "T" to the helper method as 
    // as explicit parameter. Thats it!
    template <typename T>
    class X: public T
    {
        public:
            template < typename N, std::enable_if_t< has_Foo<N>::value>* = nullptr>
                void Call_Helper() { this->Foo(); }

            template < typename N, std::enable_if_t< has_Bar<N>::value>* = nullptr>
                void Call_Helper() { this->Bar(); }

            void Call() { Call_Helper<T>(); }
    };


    int main()
    {
        X<A> xa;
        X<B> xb;

        xa.Call();
        xb.Call();
    }
```